# Awesomefont is not showing on server, locally it does

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, font-awesome

I use some icons from the awesomefont library and locally it is showing it, but on the server it isn't.

The issue lies in the URL.

Locally the URL: http://localhost:1234
Server URL: https://site.nl/sitename/

When I lookup why the font isn't loading, I see that it looks for the font files in https://site.nl and not in https://site.nl/sitename

my bundle config looks like this:

[image]

The font files are in the fonts folder in the root of the application.

[image]

I would like it to work always, both locally and on the server.
How can I do this?

For now I fixed it on the server by adding a virtual folder on https://site.nl that points to the fonts folder of the site.
It shows the icons now, but this seems like a quick-and-dirty solution.

Comment: If the app-relative URLs are resolving to the root of the site rather than the root of the application, it sounds like the `sitename` folder on your server isn't configured as an application in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

you can check two things

as mentioned in the comment most likely the actual font files are not being found. If you look in the font awesome CSS file you will probably see something like:

@font-face { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot'); }

Add this to your web.config: [webconfig setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9gPT.jpg)

Comment: Don't add code as an image. Paste it directly to your answer.

Comment: The code for the webconfig didn't work.
I have added a virtual folder to the fonts folder and that did work. Not sure if is a good solution, but it gives me more time to figure out one.